# Warm air goes up: reason on a microscopic scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

I was wondering about the **microscopic** reason why for example when I open the window in the winter the colder air from outside is more likely to be distributed on the floor (of course only in the first time when the air in the room have not yet thermally equilibrated everywhere).
On a **macroscopic** scale I know that the difference in the density together with Archimedes principle leads to the right reasoning.

Comment: Worth a read? http://www.nsta.org/publications/news/story.aspx?id=52428

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that there exists already a question of this type which was posted 5 years ago... Although after reading the answers given on that question in the link i am already not satisfied enough with the explanations. Since its pretty much the same question you can close this post or leave it and someone maybe now can give a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. as far as i understood the explanation on that site is based upon the principle of buoyancy and thus have an macroscopic character

Comment: I an afraid there is not what are you asking for. The more close I can get is in the bigger mean free path for hotter molecules. On average and during equilibration it causes the "rising" . But it seems interconnected to thermalisation. More complicated that at a first glance. Hopefully someone will answer in clear way....

Comment: @valerio92 - Unfortunately, that question is not very well posed. (But then again, neither is this one).

Comment: @DavidHammen Well yes, neither of them is very well posed but I think that the OPs are basically asking about the same concept.

Comment: Johnny90 - You are demanding an answer which does not exist. A microscopic sized packet of warm air won't rise much; it will merely dissipate its energy. The behavior you are asking about is an emergent behavior; a microscopic explanation does not exist.

Comment: @valerio92 - I agree; it's asking pretty much the same question.